# How to download specific parts of website with wget?

Tags: linux, wget, downloading-website-files

I want to download only the css reference part from w3schools.com. The command string below downloads the entire site. How can i achieve what i want?

```
wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P /home/username/Desktop/ http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/
```

Comment: I'd suggest you use `httrack`. It's an easy interactive website downloader, better than wget's recursive download.

Comment: This can be easily done by one or more shell script or python script. Can you give me more details of your demand?

Answer (score 1):

Add `--no-parent` argument.
All command:

```
$ wget --convert-links --no-parent https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/
```

It works.